# The sound plays very fast

Tags: sound, firefox, hdmi, soundcard, video-player

System Info:

```
Ubuntu Studio Version 22.04.2 LTS Jammy Jellyfish
Motherboard: Asus TUF Gaming X570-Plus (Wi-Fi)
CPU: 12-Core AMD Ryzen 9 3900X, 4267 MHz (42.75 x 100)
Video Card: AMD Radeon Pro WX 7100 8GB GDDR5
North Bridge chipset: AMD K17.7 IMC
BIOS type: AMI UEFI
```

I connect my PC to a 4K LG TV via HDMI converted from Display-port. The problem is that video playback for both audio and video is very fast on Firefox browser like other players.The problem disappear on Headphone.I tried some solutions shared on AskUbuntu but none worked for me. Please help!